# How to terminate a pthread that is in the middle of a blocking call?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I've got some thread **thr** that is tasked with moving data from a device over to a file. Because of the size of the data the fwrite takes several minutes to complete. During this time there is the possibility that the user may not like the data and will choose to purge it. In that event my program will be notified and I would like to kill the thread that is in the middle of this fwrite. I'm not worried about corruption of the data since it's all been deemed irrelevant but I do need things like the file descriptors to become free to the system. I can't use a mutex or have checkpoints in the thread to check if it should end since it's all being blocked by this single fwrite call. What would be the most appropriate way to terminate this thread prematurely?

some pseudo code to illustrate the scenario:

```
void * thr() {
    //open a device for reading
    //and a file for writing

    fwrite(...); //this operation takes several minutes

    //close the device
    //and file

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

main(){
    pthread_t thid;
    pthread_create(&thid, NULL, thr);

    //event that may need to terminate the thread early
}
```

Comment: Is multiple fwrite calls with checkpoints in between not an option? If you really really don't care you could dedicate a signal to this thread and `siglongjmp` out of fwrite that way.

Comment: @Quimby I could add multiple, but the problem is then I need to balance fwrite overhead with polling frequency and ideally I'd like to terminate the moment I am notified of the event, not a second later or so

Comment: I see, well, the bottom line is `fwrite` was not designed to be cancellable. I would not worry about `fwrite` overhead though, e.g. writing page-sized buffers in a loop should not be much slower, if at all. You could look into POSIX async IO which has [aio_cancel](https://linux.die.net/man/3/aio_cancel) but that is probably a lot of work for you to replace `FILE*`-based logic.

Comment: As far as I am aware, the only way to steal a thread's attention while it is blocked on I/O is to send it a signal.  Since I think `fwrite` will automatically try to restart after being interrupted by a signal, @Quimby's suggestion to use `siglongjmp` to back out is one of very few alternatives I can think of that would directly address the question.